# format section, put different string before the numbers

Tags: sectioning, formatting

i want to put some string before the numbers in subsubsection, so it should look like this

**Example 1.1.1: Sum** text

**Exercise 1.1.2: Vector** text

the string is always different but wont be longer than 10 characters, well actually 3 different strings so far. i imagined to `\renewcommand\subsubsection{...}` so i can use it with 2 arguments like this `\section{Example}{Sum}` or maybe first argument could be optional.
is it possible? If not, i could define a new counter and make a new environment using package enumitem, is it possible to make variable string before the numbers there? dont really want to make 3 new environments.

preferably for the `scrartcl` class.

Comment: How should the content be displayed/used in the ToC? Do you want `Example` (or others) to carry over there as well?

Comment: aah, forgot to mention, sorry, the toc will not contain subsubsections at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine `\sectionlinesformat` to add the prefix. For this the the prefix has to be stored in a separate macro before `\subsubsection`. This can be done by patching `\subsubsection` to store the prefix before inserting the normal title:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\let\originalsectionlinesformat\sectionlinesformat
\let\originalsubsubsection\subsubsection
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \expandafter\if\csname#1prefix\endcsname\relax\relax%
    \originalsectionlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}%
  \else%
    \originalsectionlinesformat{#1}{#2}{\csname#1prefix\endcsname~#3}{#4}%
  \fi%
}
\renewcommand\subsubsection[1][]{%
  \def\subsubsectionprefix{#1}\originalsubsubsection
}
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection[Example]{Subsubsection}
Actual text
\end{document}
```

[image]

If a run-in heading is used, every `linesformat` has to be replaced by `catchphraseformat`.

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick answer, but now i added `\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=-.25\baselineskip]{subsubsection}` before your code and the "Example" does not show now, how to fix it?

Comment: @A.Ston Them a run-in heading is used. I added a note for this case.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another suggestion defining a new key for the optional argument of the sectioning commands and patching `\subsubsectionformat`:

```
\documentclass[
  headings=optiontoheadandtoc
]{scrartcl}
\newcommand*\currentprefix{}
\FamilyStringKey[.section]{KOMAarg}{prefix}{\currentprefix}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\subsubsectionformat
  {\ifstr{\currentprefix}{}{}{\currentprefix\ }}
  {}{\PatchFailed}
\xapptocmd\subsubsectionformat
  {\gdef\currentprefix{}}
  {}{\PatchFailed}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  afterskip=-.25\baselineskip
]{subsubsection}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection[prefix=Example,tocentry={Title in TOC}]{Subsubsection}
\blindtext
\subsubsection[Next Title in TOC]{Next Subsubsection}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a theorem-like environment.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\makeatletter
% some small coercion on thmtools ;-)
\newcommand{\reformatNOTE}{\def\thmt@space##1(##2){##2}}
\makeatletter

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
  headformat={\NAME\ \NUMBER: \NOTE},
]{ex}

\declaretheorem[
  preheadhook=\reformatNOTE,
  style=ex,
  parent=subsection,
  name=Exercise,
]{exercise}

\declaretheorem[
  preheadhook=\reformatNOTE,
  style=ex,
  numberlike=exercise,
  name=Example
]{example}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}

\begin{example}[Sum]
Text for the example
\end{example}

\begin{exercise}[Vector]
Text for the exercise
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]